# How to replace information in the file with tokens and without PHP?

Tags: javascript, html, token

I created a small website, here are my files :

https://github.com/S1BIOSE/E-business-Card

I put these files on a free host, which uses HTML, JS, and CSS. It does not support PHP.

I want to create tokens to replace the information in the JS, HTML, JSON, XML, and TXT files. For example :

- A token with the name of the company.
- A token with the url of the website.
- A token with the description of the company.

Comment: Where do you want to load these tokens from? Do you want them to be files or perhaps they should be part of your url?

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen For example, I would like to change the name of the company "Mathieu LEBERT" in all the files.

Comment: With a little effort you could convert the repository to using Jekyll and host the site on Github pages for free, with custom domain, and use a _config.yml to store some of the variables/tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the files on the fly without some kind of server side programming.

On the frontend you could have tokens in your URL or loaded via [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).

Here is an example using the query string in the URL:

```js
function LoadAndApplyTokens() {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(tag => {
    for (let i = 0; i < tag.childNodes.length; i++) {
      const child = tag.childNodes[i];
      if (child.nodeName.toLowerCase() != '#text') {
        continue;
      }
      let val = child.nodeValue;
      let change = false;
      let variables = val.match(/::[^:]+::/img);
      if (variables == null)
        continue;
      variables.forEach(variable => {
        if (urlParams.has(variable.substr(2, variable.length - 4))) {
          const variableValue = urlParams.get(variable.substr(2, variable.length - 4));
          while (val.indexOf(variable) >= 0) {
            val = val.replace(variable, variableValue);
          }
          change = true;
        }
      });
      if (change) {
        child.nodeValue = val;
        console.log(child.parentNode, val);
      }
    }
  });
}
window.addEventListener("load", LoadAndApplyTokens);
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>My name is <b>::name::</b></h1>
  <p><b>Description of ::name::</b><br/>::name:: is a company</p>
</div>
<form method="get">
  <label>Name: <input name="name" /></label>
  <button type="submit">Change</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok thanks I understand, so it is only possible to edit HTML? I will not be able to modify the content of JS or CSS files with this solution?

Comment: Well you could have a [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) element in your HTML, that the above function could manipulate. But the right way to do this would probably be some sort of server side function.